# google map as background to my canvas drawing

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Basically I am drawing circles in "canvas" based on user input and I want that these circles are drawn over google map as the background of the canvas.

I saw number of code sample where google map is used over div tag but how to get it with canvas.

Please see this is what I tried.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var map_options = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
    var ctx = document.getElementById("map_canvas").getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
    ctx.arc(10, 10, 12, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.font = 'bold 10pt Courier';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillText(10, 10, 13);
    ctx.closePath();
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="map_canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using a wrapper div (with the needed dimensions) containing the google-maps content and your canvas in it. For example could you position your canvas absolute (`top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;` to use it's parents full dimensions and like `z-index: 10` to definitely put it over the map).

A jsFiddle made from your source-code: https://jsfiddle.net/v7d6qyh0/

**HTML**

```
<div id="canvas-wrapper">
  <canvas id="map_canvas"></canvas>
  <canvas id="my_canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function initialize() {
  var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
  var map_options = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
  var ctx = document.getElementById("my_canvas").getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
  ctx.arc(10, 10, 12, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.font = 'bold 10pt Courier';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.fillText(10, 10, 13);
  ctx.closePath();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Changed the line for `var ctx =` get a different canvas.

**CSS**

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

#canvas-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
}

#map_canvas {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 7px 1px blue;
}

#my_canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

---

*//UPDATE:*

New jsFiddle with working Map and Canvas: https://jsfiddle.net/y4zgfqmr/ (Map as Iframe due to missing API-Key, but with your coordinates.)

**HTML**

```
<div id="canvas-wrapper">
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2843.7718513478367!2d-78.54848868412537!3d44.540303802631506!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x0!2zNDTCsDMyJzI1LjEiTiA3OMKwMzInNDYuNyJX!5e0!3m2!1sde!2sde!4v1461144974851" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <div id="my_canvas-container">
    <canvas id="my_canvas" width="600" height="450"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("my_canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
ctx.arc(320, 190, 12, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
ctx.fill();
ctx.font = 'bold 10pt Courier';
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.textAlign = 'center';
ctx.fillText(10, 320, 193);
ctx.closePath();
```

**CSS**

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

#canvas-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
}

#my_canvas-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
#my_canvas-container > #my_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: So you actually don't want to place a canvas layer over your map, but maybe markers in the map? (Should your drawn circles move, when you move the map?)

Comment: No my circles can be constant I can drag the map and adjust the circle to the desired place. I know because of the canvas layer I am not able to access it.

Comment: I just need a circle drawn over the map from javascript (because I am getting the x and y axis from the user) it doesn't matter if it comes from canvas or anything else.

Comment: In that case just set `pointer-events: none` on `my_canvas-container` and you're good to go. https://jsfiddle.net/y4zgfqmr/1/   :)